# Compiler says a parameter is type struct ** when I defined it as struct *

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I think I might be misunderstanding how passing pointers as parameters in C functions works. In the past I have cheated and used global variables and large, single C files with all of the functions in it. I am trying to learn how to use separate C files and link them into a single executable.

Room is a typedeffed struct.

I have prototyped the function in a guarded header file called functions.h:

```
void init_rooms(Room *rooms[], Room *current_room);
/* (pointer to the room struct array, pointer to current room) */
```

I then included that header both in main.c and functions.c.

The function definition in functions.c is:

```
void init_rooms(Room *rooms[], Room *current_room){
current_room = rooms[0];
...}
```

I call the function in main.c like this:

```
Room * current_room; /* pointer to current player location */
Room * rooms = malloc(sizeof(struct room)*NUM_ROOMS); /* allocate memory for rooms */
init_rooms(rooms, current_room);
```

And I get this error:

```
main.c|11|error: incompatible pointer types passing 'Room *' (aka 'struct room *') to parameter of type 'Room **' (aka 'struct room **'); take the address with & [-Werror,-Wincompatible-pointer-types]|
```

Now, I'm pretty sure I haven't defined any pointers to pointers here, and it looks to me like I've got the types all the same. Why is the compiler saying that the parameter is **type?

I'm using Clang on Linux, if that makes any difference.

EDIT: I also tried dereferencing the pointers as the compiler suggested, but it then gave me a different error.

Comment: clang errors are really clear to me.

Comment: If it were clear to me, I wouldn't have bothered you all!

Comment: `Room *rooms[]` : `rooms` is array of pointer of `Room`. `Room * rooms` is pointer to `Room`.

Comment: @Andomonir sorry I didn't meant to be rude, my advice was to read carefully that error, and given clang has usually good error messages the error is easy to understand given it seems you somewhat understand pointer basics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`init_rooms()` doesn't take a `Room *`. It takes an *array* of them (`Room *rooms[]`), which is essentially equivalent to

```
void init_rooms(Room **rooms, Room *current_room);
```

Without seeing the rest of the code, there's a good chance you want that function to begin:

```
void init_rooms(Room *rooms, Room *current_room)
{
  current_room = rooms;
```

but be aware that `current_room` will only be changed *inside* the function. If you want its value to change *outside*, do this:

```
void init_rooms(Room *rooms, Room **current_room)
{  
  *current_room = rooms;
```

and call it as:

```
init_rooms(rooms, &current_room);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the function argument: `Room *rooms[]`
In C, arrays are just pointers - and an array of pointers, is just a pointer to a pointer... :)

In your case, defining `Room *room[]` is the same as `Room **room`

You might want to change it to `Room *rooms`